# Customizing grouped bar graph colors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, fill

I am trying to change the fill colors of the bars based on their variable (male or female)

This is my code that works:

```
ggplot(sex_excercise_genhlth, aes(genhlth, prop_exer, fill=sex)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black", position="dodge" ) + labs(title="Proportions of males to females who exercised in last 30 days compared to their general health", x="General Health", y="Proportion Exercise")
```

[image: plot]

When I add the following code I get an error:

```
+scale_fill_manual(values=c(“blue”,“pink”))
```

Comment: Hi! what error did you get? And to make it reproducible, can you dput(sex_excercise_genhlth) and paste the output as part of your post?

Comment: You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with creating a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269). See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5)

Comment: In your example here, you've got smart quotes in `c(“blue”,“pink”)`. Is that the case in your real code?

Comment: Also, you didn't start a new line with the "+" did you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of how you might correctly use `scale_fill_manual` for your use case:

First I'll create some dummy data:

```r
df <- data.frame(sex = rep(c("Male", "Female"), 5),
           place = rep(letters[1:5], each = 2),
           vals = rep(c(0.1, 0.2), 5) + seq(0.9, 0.45, -0.05))
```

Now the plot

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = place, y = vals)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           colour = "black", 
           aes(fill = sex), 
           position = "dodge") +
   labs(title="Proportions of people exercising", 
        x="General Health", 
        y="Proportion Exercise") +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("pink", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: You don't have to set the labels; take that part out and your code still runs fine

Comment: @camille thank you; you are right. I'll change this answer.

Comment: @camille I think adding "labels" does give you direct control over which level goes with which colour, though if you know the order of your factors you don't need it.

Comment: This worked and was super helpful! I'm a beginner so do you think you can explain to me what the you were telling the program to do in each line of the data.frame portion?

Comment: @SabrinaReich sure. `rep` just means repeat, so `rep(c("Male", "Female"), 5)` just repeats "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female" ... until `sex` is length 10. `letters` is a built-in vector of lowercase letters, so `letters[1:5]` just gives me a, b, c, d and e as characters. This time I repeat them using 'each' so the sequence will be a, a, b, b, c, c, d, d, e, e. Finally, I use `rep` to alternate between 0.1 and 0.2 (5 times each), and to this I add a sequence of decreasing numbers using `seq`.

Comment: @SabrinaReich If the answer has solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted to help other users with similar problems to find an answer. Thanks